# PHP Output buffer

Tags: php, debugging, output

My own PHP framework parses files like this to grab the content:

```
ob_start();
include($file);
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

However, now I am working on an own `error_handler` to display an error page if any error occured even when it's happning in a template parsed like the code piece demonstrates above.

The funny thing is the content of the included template is printed to the browser when code execution dies due to an error for example. That of course makes my error-page looks very bad.

Shouldn't the opening of an output buffer prevent printing the content?

Especially because ob_get_clean() should clear the content after parsing it.

Why is this happening?

If I don't run into an error the website is working as intended.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You mean `$file` contains code to execute, as opposed to passive markup or data?

Comment: $file contains mostly HTML content that is being printed out. Its the HTML code of the website and ofcourse also contains PHP code like loops and if conditions. A normal website view as this is a MVC pattern based framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problem. Try using ob_clean():

```
try {
    $app = new App($some_config);
    $app->run();
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
    ob_clean();
    // Display your error page.
}
```